# Why are the file descriptors for TcpListener and the produced TcpStream different?

Tags: rust, tcp, file-descriptor

I am trying to investigate file descriptors and how they interact with tcp connections in Rust, I am quite new to both Rust programming and Unix.

Ultimately, I want to bind the stdio of some program to a tcp send/receive by matching up their file descriptors. For now, I just want to understand how the file descriptors are allocated, and why they get different values.

I wrote this simple code to experiment:

```
use std::{
    net::TcpListener,
    os::fd::AsFd
};

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:1024").unwrap();
    println!("Listener fd: {:?}", listener.as_fd());
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        println!("Stream fd: {:?}", stream.as_fd());
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get a first line printed of:

```
Listener fd: BorrowedFd { fd: 3 }
```

And when I subsequently send some data to the tcp listener it prints lines as I expect which look like:

```
Stream fd: BorrowedFd { fd: 4 }
```

What I want to understand is:

- Why are the file descriptors different?
- What does each file descriptor correspond to, i.e. does using 3 correspond to the incoming data of the connection, and 4 to the data I could write back to the stream?

Comment: Because one belongs to the listening socket and the other belongs to the accepted socket.

Comment: So would that mean that in terms of redirecting stdio through a socket then the accepted one is what I am interested in?

Comment: Yes, The listening socket can't perform any I/O. It can only accept connections.

Comment: So, if I read and write from the same file descriptor, how does the OS know which it is doing?

Comment: Eh? Which what? The OS knows whether you are reading or writing. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. I guess its probably trivial then, but it seems like if I set my stdout and stdin to the same file descriptor then I might end up overwriting what I am supposed to be reading in. Does that make sense? Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please clarify.

Comment: The tcp stream can both provide me data that someone sent me, and also let me write to it so that it can send that message to someone. So, I can read from the stream and also write to it. If I want to write to it from a process's stdout, then I can match up the file descriptors so that the stdout goes to the tcp stream. Equally, I can match the tcp stream to the process's stdin so that it can provide input. If these use the same file descriptor, how is it that they don't interfere with each other?

Comment: What I naively expect would be to have a file descriptor for writing to and a different file descriptor for reading from, so I am trying to understand how the tcp driver or something knows how to function without this.

Comment: A file descriptor is just an opaque handle the kernel exposes towards some functionality. Handle #3 gives you the possibility to call `accept()` and produce further handles (such as your #4). Handle like #4 represents a socket connected to a peer. #4 supports operations like `read()` and `write()`, which don't interfere with each other simply because they're different operations and the OS knows how to distinguish them. Behind that number 4 there is a whole data structure inside the kernel, and that data structure can have separate read and write buffers, control flow flags, etc.

Comment: That's clear, thank you for your answers and continued patience:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file descriptor is an opaque handle the kernel exposes towards some functionality. In your case file descriptor #3 is obtained by [`socket()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) and [bound](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html) to a port. That in turn allows you to call [`accept()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html#) on it to obtain further file descriptors (such as your #4) that can be used to communicate with different connected clients.

File descriptor #4 is your handle to the connected peer. It supports operations like [`read()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html#) and [`write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html#) (and many others, such as [`select()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html#)). These are the same operations normally provided on file descriptors that correspond to open files, which is how Unix provides polymorphism.

Reads and writes on the same file descriptor don't interfere with each other simply because they're different operations and the OS is smart enough to distinguish them. Behind number 4 the kernel keeps an entire data structure that contains separate read and write buffers, control flow flags, and much more. It's only in the user space that it's represented as a single number, which you can think of as an index into a table kept in the kernel.

Comment: The first one was obtained from `socket()`, the second from `accept()`. `bind()` does not return an FD.

Comment: @user207421 Fixed, thanks!